# Constructor string parameter not setting window title

Tags: c++, class, constructor, window, title

The window title in the title bar is not setting to the variable and string i assign it.

I have show my code below but the problem is `app::Window * wnd = new app::Window(L"Window Title");` constructor does seem to be 'tstring mWindowName;' but this `mhWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, className.c_str(), mWindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 200, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight, nullptr, nullptr, mhInstance, this);` is not setting the title.

Window.h

```
#ifndef _ST_Window_H_
#define _ST_Window_H_

// include files
//#include "s-window.h"
#include "s-platform.h"
#include "s-safe-delete-and-release.h"
#include "s-iostream.h"
#include "s-strings.h"

#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#include <windows.h>
#endif //_WINDOWS_

namespace app
{
class Window
{
protected:
    HINSTANCE mhInstance;
    HWND mhWnd;
    tstring mWindowName;
    bool mRunState;
    long int mScreenWidth;
    long int mScreenHeight;

public:
    Window(void);
    Window(tstring windowName);
    ~Window(void);

    int Setup(long int width, long int height);

    LRESULT MessageProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    int Run(void);

    inline HINSTANCE GetInstance(void) { return mhInstance; }
    inline HWND GetHwnd(void) { return mhWnd; }
    inline long GetWidth(void) { return mScreenWidth; }
    inline long GetHeight(void) { return mScreenHeight; }
    inline tstring GetWindowName(void) { return mWindowName; }
    inline bool GetRunState(void) { return mRunState; }

protected:
    int Create(void);
};
}

#endif //!_ST_Window_H_
```

Window.cpp

```
// include files
#include "sit-window.h"

using namespace std;

namespace app
{
Window::Window(void) : mhInstance(GetModuleHandle(0)), mhWnd(nullptr), mWindowName(nullptr),
    mRunState(true), mScreenWidth(0), mScreenHeight(0) 
{

}

Window::Window(tstring windowName) : mhInstance(GetModuleHandle(0)), mhWnd(nullptr),
    mWindowName(windowName), mRunState(true), mScreenWidth(0), mScreenHeight(0) 
{

}

Window::~Window(void) 
{

}

int Window::Setup(long int width, long int height) 
{
    mScreenWidth = width;
    mScreenHeight = height;
    return Create();
}

LRESULT Window::MessageProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    Window * wnd;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT * pcs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;

        wnd = (Window*)pcs->lpCreateParams;
        wnd->mhWnd = hwnd;

        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pcs->lpCreateParams);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        wnd = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }

    if (wnd)
        return wnd->MessageProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int Window::Run(void)
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
};

int Window::Create(void) {
    WNDCLASSEX wnd;
    SecureZeroMemory(&wnd, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wnd.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wnd.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wnd.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wnd.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 3);
    wnd.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wnd.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wnd.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wnd.hInstance = mhInstance;
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;

    tstring className = mWindowName;
    className.append(L" - WndCls");

    wnd.lpszClassName = className.c_str();
    wnd.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wnd.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wnd))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Window class not registered!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }

    RECT rect = { 0, 0, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight };

    if (!AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false, NULL))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to adjust window rect!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }
    else
    {
        mScreenWidth = rect.right;
        mScreenHeight = rect.bottom;
    }


    mhWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, className.c_str(), mWindowName.c_str(),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 200, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight,
        nullptr, nullptr, mhInstance, this);

    if (!mhWnd)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Window not created!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }

    if (ShowWindow(mhWnd, SW_SHOW))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to show window!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }

    if (!UpdateWindow(mhWnd))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to update window!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }

    if (!SetForegroundWindow(mhWnd))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to set to foreground!" << std::endl;
        mRunState = false;
        return 0x0;
    }

    return 0x0;
}
}
```

Main.cpp

```
// include files
//#include "s-safe-delete-and-release.h"
//#include "s-window.h"
#include "sit-window.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "serenity-core.lib")

// namespaces
using namespace std;

// statics
//long int srnty::Window::mScreenWidth = 1024;
//long int srnty::Window::mScreenHeight = 768;

// win main entry point
namespace win {
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    wcout << L"WinMain() called..." << endl;

    app::Window * wnd = new app::Window(L"Window Title");

    wnd->Setup(1024, 768);

    int result = wnd->Run();

    SafeDelete(wnd);

    return result; 
}
}

// main entry point
int main(int argv, char argc[])
{
// detect memory leaks in the application
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);

_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(0);

int mlCount = _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
wcout << L"Number of memory Leaks: " << to_wstring(mlCount) << endl;
assert(mlCount == 0);
#endif

wcout << L"main() called..." << endl;

win::WinMain(GetModuleHandle(0), nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOW);

wchar_t title[1024];
wchar_t titleBuffer[1024];
GetConsoleTitle(titleBuffer, 1024);
//wsprintf(title, L"%d", GetCurrentProcessId());    
SetConsoleTitle(title);
Sleep(40);
HWND hwndFound = FindWindow(NULL, title);
SetForegroundWindow(hwndFound);

system("pause");
return 0x0;
}
```

I expect `tstring mWindowName;` to set the window Title in the title bar when used here `mhWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, className.c_str(), mWindowName.c_str(),   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 200, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight, nullptr, nullptr, mhInstance, this);`. The initialization of the `tstring mWindowName;` is through the constructor in Main.cpp `app::Window * wnd = new app::Window(L"Window Title");`

Comment: Duplicate of [Created windows have no title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216797/created-windows-have-no-title). You are not calling `DefWindowProc` in your `WM_NCCREATE` handler.

Comment: Thank you. You were 100% right. I will answer the question with the information you gave and show how it was implemented for others to see, if they encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Chen above clearly pointed out. This was an oversight on my behalf.

In the Window.cpp file `LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` never returned control the `DefWindowProc` function there for the never sets the title.

The fucntion should look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    Window * wnd;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT * pcs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;

        wnd = (Window*)pcs->lpCreateParams;
        wnd->mhWnd = hwnd;

        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pcs->lpCreateParams);
        //return TRUE;
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        wnd = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }

    if (wnd)
        return wnd->MessageProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Thank you i hope this helps someone else.