# The windows title defined in CreateWindowW function isn't displayed

Tags: windows, winapi

I created a window with the `CreateWindowW` function (after registering the windows class etc) and it works fine, but the title of the window isn't displayed. I could solve the problem with the `SetWindowTextW` function but still I'm wondering why it doesn't work the normal way.

That's my register function:

```
ATOM MainWindow::RegisterMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APP_ICON));
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName = windowsClass;
wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
```

My create function…:

```
BOOL MainWindow::CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
hwnd = CreateWindowW(windowsClass, L"FLY", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    PublicMainClass::userData.MainWindow.left, PublicMainClass::userData.MainWindow.top,
    PublicMainClass::userData.MainWindow.right, PublicMainClass::userData.MainWindow.bottom, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, NULL/*this*/);

SetWindowTextW(hwnd, windowsTitle);

if (!hwnd)
{
    return FALSE;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
return TRUE;
}
```

And my constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
PublicMainClass::userData.NewUser();

PublicMainClass::PublicMainClassConstructor(hInstance);

LoadStringW(hInstance, MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS, windowsClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, APP_TITLE, windowsTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
}
```

That's how the wWinMain function calls the class:

```
MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow(hInstance);
mainWindow->RegisterMainWindow(hInstance);
mainWindow->CreateMainWindow(hInstance);
```

And that's my window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_NCCREATE:
{
    CREATESTRUCT *pcs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
    //MainWindow* mainWindow = (MainWindow*)pcs->lpCreateParams;
    //mainWindow->hwnd = hWnd;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)pcs->lpCreateParams);

    /*Taskbar *taskbar = new Taskbar();
    taskbar->RegisterTaskbarWindow();
    taskbar->CreateTaskbarWindow(hWnd);*/

    /*WorkSpace *workspace = new WorkSpace();
    workspace->RegisterWorkSpaceWindow();
    workspace->CreateWorkSpaceWindow(hWnd);*/
    return TRUE;
}
break;
case WM_CREATE:
{
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
}
break;
case WM_CLOSE:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
break;
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    MainWindow *mainWindow = (MainWindow*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    if (mainWindow) mainWindow->hwnd = 0;
    return TRUE;
}
break;
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    MainWindow *mainWindow = (MainWindow*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    POINT pointer;
    pointer.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    pointer.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    mainWindow->OnClk(&pointer);
    return TRUE;
}
break;
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
{
    MainWindow *mainWindow = (MainWindow*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    POINT pointer;
    pointer.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    pointer.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

    return TRUE;
}
break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Must be a problem with your code

Comment: The code shown is not passing `windowsTitle` to `CreateWindowW()`.  If you are going to ask for help with code that is not work, please show the code that is not working!

Comment: `windowsTitle` is a `WCHAR[100]` variable, but to highlight the problem I replaced it by `L"FLY"` which has the same problem

Comment: The last parameter of `CreateWindowW` is a pointer of `CREATESTRUCTA` struct, this pointer will be sent to the callback function `MainWndProc`, Could you provide your code of `MainWndProc`?

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]

Comment: I bet it is [Created windows have no title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216797/created-windows-have-no-title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that since I processed the `WM_NCCREATE` message in the window's procedure, it wasn't processed by the `DefWindowProc()` function. The WM_NCCREATE function should be processed as follows:

```
case WM_NCCREATE:
{
    CREATESTRUCTW* create = (CREATESTRUCTW*)lParam;
    SetWindowTextW(hWnd, create->lpszName);
    return TRUE;
}
```